# Yii2 Переадресация

Tags: php, yii2, redirect

Есть модель для формы в ней из одного метода надо пользователя перенаправить на другую страницу. Делаю так:

```
...Модель...
public function test(){
    return Yii::$app->response->redirect(['notactivated']);
}
...
```

Но почему то происходит переход на главную индексную страницу вместо страницы notactivated.php.

Еще пробовал:

```
...Модель...
public function test(){
    return Yii::$app->response->redirect(['site/notactivated']);
}
...
```

И та же ситуация.

В чем может быть причина?

_____ ДОБАВЛЕНО ______

код контроллера:

```
class SiteController extends Controller
{
    public function actionNotactivated()
    {
        return $this->render('notactivated');
    }
}
```

код модели

```
class LoginForm extends Model
{
public function login()
    {
        $u = Users::find()->where(['name' => $this->username])->one();

        if ($u->activated == 0){
            return Yii::$app->response->redirect(['site/notactivated']); // вот тут я пытался сделать редирект
            //return Yii::$app->response->redirect(Url::to(['site/about']));
            //return $this->redirect(Url::to(['site/about']));
        }

        if ($this->validate()) {
            return Yii::$app->user->login($this->getUser(), $this->rememberMe ? 3600*24*30 : 0);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Во первых я бы вынес редирект из модели в контроллер, а во вторых не помешал бы код самого контроллера

Comment: действительно из контроллера работает как должно. тогда назревает вопрос, а возможно ли вызвать метод контроллера из модели? контроллер родной из yii2 controllers\SiteController.php. Мне при ошибке в модели нужно перенаправлять на страницу с предупреждением.

Comment: Можно всё, но попахивает какой-то садомией.

Comment: Добавьте код контроллера в котором вызывается модель и что именно вам нужно сделать

Comment: @Ninazu добавил код

Comment: Обновил свой ответ

Comment: Thanks, Ninazu.
It's works for me!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public function actionTest() {
    $model = new Model();

    if ($model->test()) {
        Yii::$app->response->redirect(Url::to('site/notactivated'));
    }
}
```

**Обновленно**

```
public function actionLogin() {
    $model = new LoginForm();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && !$model->login()) {
        return $this->render('notactivated');
    }

    return $this->render('login');
}
```

И в модели

```
class LoginForm extends Model {

    public function login() {
        if (!$this->validate()) {
            return false;
        }

        $u = Users::find()->where(['name' => $this->username])->one();

        if ($u->activated == 0) {
            return false;
        }

        return Yii::$app->user->login($this->getUser(), $this->rememberMe ? 3600 * 24 * 30 : 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: на `$this->redirect` будет ругаться что нет такого метода. и какой смысл использовать `actionTest()` если мне надо из внешней модели вызвать страницу, я бы мог без перенаправления вызвать метод контролера `actionNotactivated()`.

Comment: Что значит из внешней модели вызвать страницу? Вы же эту модель используете в каком-то экшене, вот оттуда и делайте редирект

Comment: мне нужно из модели регистрации пользователя если он ввел не те данные отправить его на страницу с ошибкой, страница с ошибкой висит на actionNotactivated(){} контроллере site. Как мне кажется я в модели регистрации пользователя могу просто вызвать метод actionNotactivated(){} контроллера site. Только не знаю как это сделать. Вот пробовал редирект, а он не работает в моделях.

Comment: все узрел свою проблему, большое спасибо.